# How to show insecure images in an SSL client without a warning to the user?

Tags: ssl, email-client

I've written a simple email client which is served over https.

I want to let my user's see their emails with images, but not all images in emails are served over ssl.

I was thinking that a caching/url rewrite mechanism (similar to what gmail does) would be my only option, but are there other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: The warnings are there for good reason.  They are there to warn the user that data has been sent in an insecure fashion, and that it could have been intercepted and even modified by a third party while in transit.  What you are doing is exposing your users' data, which is a bad thing.  At least warn them.

Comment: *"Did you see that I am using https?"*  Yes, I did.  *"... but not all images in emails are served over ssl"* - Images in emails are user data!  You absolutely ARE exposing user data!

Comment: 1) I didn't get it because you didn't explain yourself properly.  Period.  2) My point still stands.  People deserve to be warned if they are viewing images that are being delivered to them insecurely ... irrespective of who is doing that.  From a security perspective, the gmail approach is better than suppressing the warnings.

Comment: Hopefully, my comments will be instructive to other users who are attempting to do what you are (misguidedly IMO) trying to do.

Comment: Anyway - *"I didn't say anywhere that I wanted to suppress the warnings."* versus *"How to show insecure images in an SSL client without a warning to the user?"*.  Do you see a contradiction here?

Comment: I'm not daft.  But I suspect that maybe you haven't yet figured out what I'm telling you.  Anyway, the answer is probably that you can't do it without convincing the user to install a trusted plugin / add-on to their browser.  And that would be a bad thing from multiple perspectives.